# Ricoh SP 212 SUw - Faded prints

Tags: printing, printer

I have Ricoh SP 212 SUw. Its not a color printer. Lately, I'm having this issue of faded prints. It was fine in the beginning. I haven't used it much either. So far, I have taken maybe 150 prints (text, not images). For some reason, the print cartridge gets paper material left on it once the paper goes through it. I'm not sure what word to use. You know those tiny microfibres of paper? Can't be seen in an image. So I take out the cartridge, blow on it, put it back in. And next 1-2 prints are fine then from third page onwards same thing and it just gets worse and worse. I lost its receipt so I can't take it back to the place I bought it from. I will need to find a solution myself. I'm attaching images of a few printed pages I just took.

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0JD9.jpg)

[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmay7.jpg)

[Third page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c2KY.jpg)

[Fourth page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD6uo.jpg)

[Seventh page (skipped ahead to show print deterioration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dz65.jpg)

[Eighth page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVM0R.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That could be the result of the paper stock that you're using. To be sure, try printing with 80gm or 100gsm laser printer paper.

If the issue goes away, you'll need to consider changing paper stock. If the issue still continues on laser paper, you may need to replace the toner cartridge, as it could be an issue with the charge drum in the cartridge.